# Nested for loop will not work. Syntax?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

Why this code does not work? The console.log in the second loop does not fire.

```
this.afDatabase.list(`data/users/${this.currentUserID}/visits/`, ref => ref.orderByChild('type').equalTo('study')).snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
  return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));})
  .take(1).subscribe(data => {


  let studys1 = [];
  let studys2 = [];

  for (let i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    studys1.push(data[i]);

    for(let j=0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
      console.log(data[i][j]); //This not fires. I see nothing in the console
      studys2.push(data[i][j]) // Neither...
    }
  }

  console.log('Parent Length: ' + studys1.length); // Works
  console.log('Child Length: ' + studys2.length); //Always 0

});
```

The data I want to get:

[image]

`console.log('%O',data)` gives the following output:

[image: Where the arrow shows is the nested object I need]

Any idea?

Comment: `console.log('%O',data)` would help by giving what `data` looks like.

Comment: I edited my post with the console.log data you need. :)

Comment: the data items aren't arrays, they're objects. you can iterate an object but it's different than array iteration. Just search typescript object iteration.

Comment: Are you wanting to push the values of `age` `country` `date` etc into `studys2`? `Object.keys(obj)` may be helpful.

Comment: No, I need to count the child objects. So in the example above the result of console.log('studys2.length') has to be 1..

Answer (score 1):

Iterating an object is different from iterating an array, your can use a `for-in` to iterate through objects:

```
for(var i in data){
  for(var j in data[i]){
    console.log(data[i][j]);
    studys2.push(data[i][j]);
  };
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, that´s a progress. But I don´t need all data from object child. I need to count only the object child himself. So in the example above the result of `console.log('studys2.length')` has to be `1`...

Comment: @eleinad don't know if i got it right. You just want the content that's inside the first child key? In your case the content inside `-KyaYm...`?

Comment: Not the content, just the count. Explanation: I need to know the count all entrys with "study" as type. I have parent entrys and child entrys. So I need the count of all to build the sum. That´s all :-)

Comment: So you have Objects inside an array, and want to get the count of objects which have type = "study", am I getting this right?